# OpenGL functional example needed in Android

Tags: android

Does anybody have and want to share layout.xml file and working Activity class in which have example of using OpenGL in android ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one I know of...
http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/glsurfaceview.html

Sorry, no layout.xml (but how hard can it be to find as this was the first result in my google search?)

Answer (score 0):

I find this website to be immensely useful in learning OpenGL as a whole, along with how to use it in Android: http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/.

The original C++ tutorials (ported to many other languages also) are available [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01) for reference.